# Additional checks during OIDC PAR

Tags: openid-connect, openid

I am implementing an OIDC Provider with FAPI 1 standards. I was reading about Push Authorization Request (PAR) - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9126 The backchannel authentication with request objects before we start the flow is exactly what we need.

However, using some OIDC Providers like https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider don't allow extending past the basic request objects checks during the PAR. For example, we want to check the client has provided some extra details during onboarding so I want to call another API.

I could certainly fork the library and add in the additional checks but is this the right thing to do?

Comment: There are various extension points in `oidc-provider` that you can use to add additional behaviour. Either at PAR directly or at the point the resulting `request_uri` is used at the authorization endpoint. Which extension mechanism to go for depends entirely on the nature of the needed behaviour.

Comment: I see. https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider doesn't seem to offer extensions but I guess I can fork it. Is there an RFC available that mentions extensions?